# MySQL: Expression of generated column contains disallowed function? CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have a table with a virtual generated column that concatenates five other columns (int and char) using CONCAT_WS(). This table contains 200-odd records and is never updated - it's just used as a lookup table. Recently, after months of untroubled processing, when I update records in a child table during which a SELECT is performed on this table, I sometimes see this error (ignore the "ITEM UPDATE FAILED" - that's me):

[image]

I am in development with a many changes every day, so it is impossible for me to determine if there is a correlating change. I have recently added "created" and "lastmodified" datetime fields to several tables with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for DEFAULT or ON UPDATE, but not to this table.

Here's the table:

[image]

{EDIT} --- adding table definition:

```
 CREATE TABLE `cpct_fixedfield` (
 `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `label` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `field` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `start` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `rectype` int(11) NOT NULL ,
 `mediatype` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
 `length` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `userdefined` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `defaultval` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `helpcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `mandatory` varchar(2) NOT NULL ,
  `idx` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat_ws('.',`field`,`rectype`,`mediatype`,`start`,`length`)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

---

The length of the data in field never exceeds 11chars. I can view the entire table in pma or Mysql Workbench and the virtual field materialises in all records without complaint, which suggests to me that there is nothing wrong with either the expression for the virtual column or the data in the columns that expression draws on.

The error occurs in several contexts when I am updating a child table. All the updates occur in Stored Procedures/Functions. One section of code that seems to trigger the error is this:

```
SET idxvar = CONCAT_WS(".", SUBSTRING(tmpfldkey,3,1), rectype, ptype, position, "%") COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
SELECT id INTO ffid FROM cpct_fixedfield WHERE idx LIKE idxvar AND idx != "0.0..6.2";
```

All the variables involved are varchars or ints. utf8mb4_general_ci is used throughout the database.

I cannot find any reference in MYSQL documentation to CONCAT or CONCAT_WS being unsafe, and none of the columns referenced has a default using a non-deterministic function. All the other questions I can find in this forum and elsewhere about this error have arisen because of the use of non-deterministic functions like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() in the virtual field, or a component of the field.

I replaced the SELECT on the table with a (large) CASE statement and all was well, and in fact, after I did this then reverted to the SELECT I had no errors for many hours. But it just happened again (so I'm back to the case statement).

I have run out of ideas - I'm hoping someone has some knowledge/experience that can help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share table information as `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` it really helps if someone wants to try to repeat this. Which MySQL version?

Comment: Done - Sorry - thght the table wld suffice

Comment: MySQL version : 5.7.28

Comment: Cannot reproduce - the table is created successfully. [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8QJczvuwXJaSEUCw8ubL5Q/0). PS. The error message looks like one which must be produced by MySQL version 5.6.x...

Comment: The error is intermittent and clearly is not because of a fault in the table defn or data, or I would not be able to list the contents of the entire table. I think the error is a side affect of some other process - I was hoping someone had experienced something similar.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 would hit a syntax error on `GENERATED` and give a 1064 error. The error given above would happen if one fat-fingered the name of the `concat_ws()` function, and spelled it `concat_xs()` or something else. MySQL would assume it's meant to be a user-defined function or stored function, neither of which are allowed in a generated column expression.

Comment: It's definitely Server version: 5.7.28 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: The table exists (for 4 months) and has 200+ rows - this error does not occur when creating the table. It happens when selecting from the table, but not always. It's intermittent. I can run the SP three times without error then on the fourth run the error shows.